# Как защитить /dev/sdX от нежелательных операций?

Tags: linux, unix

При ручном манипулировании дисками есть риск ошибиться и написать, например, `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1` вместо `sdb1`, что может привести к довольно неприятным последствиям. Есть ли возможность как-то защитить диск/раздел от подобных казусов в Linux и UNIX-системах?

Comment: вся зависит от того, что именно нужно. Хотя может просто сделать алиас на mkfs и проверять диск.

Comment: @KoVadim, нужно запретить вообще какое-либо изменение содержимого диска, и очень желательно без перезагрузки системы. Можно поставить алиас на `mkfs`, но ведь есть куча других команд, тот же `fdisk`, `cfdisk`...

Comment: пользуйтесь `UUID`

Comment: Не давать полномочия рута. Это linux. Если администратор говорит переписать sda1 - система даст это сделать.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, но ведь это не очень удобно при установке системы в терминале, да и вообще в ситуациях, когда нет возможности нормально скопировать/вставить текст.

Comment: @Мелкий, а как без рута при установке дистрибутива, например?

Comment: То вы - администратор и должны смотреть и думать над тем, что вы делаете. При установке _любой_ ОС есть возможность грохнуть нужные данные. Случайно

Comment: @Мелкий, это понятно, вопрос в том, как подстраховаться. Например, просто отключить диск (хотя в таком случае его нельзя будет читать, что тоже не очень). Когда 10 раз вводишь `/dev/sdb` в терминале, всё же есть риск ненароком вписать `sda`, особенно когда ставишь систему не первый раз за день.

Comment: тогда возможно Вы выбрали не ту профессию. хотя...

Comment: Лично я даже в графическом интерфейсе Windows умудрялся форматировать не ту флешку :(

Comment: удали файл /dev/sda1 - тогда не сможешь к нему подключиться редактором. Но система продолжит работать

Comment: @eri, а что, так можно было?) Как же просто... Попробовал переименовать `/dev/sda` и установочный USB, побочных эффектов не наблюдаю. Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: @Андрей так уже есть, добавил туда текста чтоб стала понятна идея

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смонтированный раздел можно переименовать или удалить. Устройсво при этом будет функционировать как раньше, но с ним нельзя будет сделать опасных операций. Чтение и запись файлов будут доступны как раньше.

Конечно не стоит добавлять правило в /etc/udev/rules.d/

```
KERNEL=="sdа1", RUN+="/bin/mv -f /dev/${KERNEL} /dev/${KERNEL}-save", RUN+="find /dev/disks/ -type l -lname \*/${KERNEL} -exec ln -sfT /dev/${KERNEL}-save {} \;"
```

если не разберетесь на каком этапе загрузки системы и как этот диск монтируется.

Которое переименует /dev/sda1 в /dev/sda1-save автоматически.

При удалении устройства его можно вернуть командой

```
mknod /dev/sda b 8 0
```

где `8` и  `0` - цифры драйвера из файла `/sys/class/block/sda/dev`

Comment: Спасибо, именно это мне и нужно!

Answer (score 6):

1. Не работать под рутом
2. Не работать под рутом
3. Не работать под рутом
4. Пользоваться гуевыми инструментами типа `gparted` для работы с разделами
5. Работать на светлую голову и проверять команды перед тем, как бабахнуть `Enter`
6. В некоторых случаях, можно поднять виртуалку и прокинуть в нее только нужные диски.

Comment: только пятый пункт имеет смысл.

Comment: Номер 4 позволяет пересмотреть то, что собирается сделать gparted перед тем, как она реально начнет писать на диски, так что вероятность ошибки снижается.

Визуальное предстваление дисков также снижает вероятность перепутать их.

Comment: @gbg, это справедливо, но далеко не всегда есть GUI

Comment: Всегда можно запустить xvfb или кинуть X через SSH.

Comment: ох ох. далеко не всегда это можно сделать. далеко не всегда

Comment: Опишу ситуацию, из которой вытекает исходный вопрос. На днях мне приспичило поставить Линукс-дистрибутив на внешний накопитель. Диск размечал `cfdisk`'ом, форматировал с помощью `mkfs`. На ноутбуке есть встроенный SSD, который не очень хочется задеть. Как-то так. Сами понимаете, без рута в консольном режиме диски особо не разметишь, да и систему не поставишь.

Comment: Берете виртуалку, прокидываете в нее вашу флешку и получаете тотальную изоляцию от реальной системы.

Comment: @gbg, вполне возможный вариант. Но мне всё же интересно узнать, есть ли какой-то способ блокировки дисков/разделов

Comment: Думаю, что с виртуалкой, как ни странно это наиболее прямой и малорисковый способ, так как реальная система при этом никак не модифицируется

Comment: @gbg, к тому же удобный, ибо не надо настраивать Wi-Fi, например

Comment: @gbg, ты забыл написать, что не надо работать под рутом. Со всем остальным - согласен.

Answer (score 2):

чтобы труднее было перепутать, пользуйтесь визуальными средствами, совмещёнными с дополнением путей в интерфейсе оболочки.

например, вместо `/dev/sda1` указывайте (ваше блочное устройство будет называться, конечно, по-другому) `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_ZE67B5WB-part1`.

полный состав символических ссылок для одного блочного устройства:

```
$ stat -c '%N' /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_ZE67B5WB*
'/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_ZE67B5WB' -> '../../sda'
'/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_ZE67B5WB-part1' -> '../../sda1'
'/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_ZE67B5WB-part2' -> '../../sda2'
'/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST500DM002-1BD142_ZE67B5WB-part5' -> '../../sda5'
```

также возможно полезной окажется разбивка не по идентификаторам, а по другим критериям. смотрите содержимое вот этих каталогов в вашей системе:

```
$ ls -1 /dev/disk/
by-id
by-partuuid
by-path
by-uuid
```